# I can't connect to internet via lan cable because 2032 battery died and my bios bios info is now empty

Tags: internet, bios, cable

I have a compaq CQ61-112SL from about 5 years now... the main battery is almost dead, doesn't keep more then 10 minutes. anyway my problem is that my motherboard battery didn't have any more energy left a few days ago and since then I can't access internet through lan cable but only via wifi. I need cable though. I saw that on my BIOS setup page there were a bunch of parameters missing like serial number, UUID, product number and stuff like that. Also when I start the notebook it prints something like : No serial found. or something like that.

I don't really know if the reason why my lan cable doesn't work is the empty BIOS but i assume that's it.

If it's not please enlighten me. Or anyway tell me how to update the serial number and product number to the real ones (instead of the 0000000000000 that is now in my bios).

I downloaded HP DMI which should make it possible to set these variables on the BIOS but i'm on Windows 8 64bit and the executable file that I need to open for my laptop model says it can't run on 64 bit.

Comment: Go to the store and buy a CR2032 battery.

Comment: Buy a battery, then go into the BIOS setup, and find and use the 'reset to defaults' feature.

Answer (score 1):

So… you already know the problem? You have a dead battery?

Spend the $1 on a CR2032 battery, you cheapskate.

Comment: i put the new battery on, reset to the default settings but the serial number, the product number and the UUID are still missing.

Comment: Probably needs to reset the BIOS with the jumper/switch on the mobo. See manual for directions.

Answer (score 0):

First buy a CR2032 battery and replace the empty one. They cost next to nothing and most electronics stores have them.

Then boot, go into the Bios and do a "Reset to factory defaults".
That should regenerate anything required.
If it keeps complaining about the serial/prodnum check the label on the bottom. (Often located under the battery.)
Both numbers should be listed. I have seen Compaq's that had the product number etched in the plastic of the bottom-cover in stead.

Comment: Most _grocery_ stores have them.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Not around here. AA, AAA and 9V is about all a grocery stores has in these parts. DIY stores usually don't carry them either.

Comment: yeah i have those numbers but I can't insert them directly from the BIOS menu. they are like disabled fields...

Comment: Oh... One of those... There is a Compaq service-tool to set these values (bootable CD or USB). But even most Compaq service techs don't know it exists. I have never been able to get my hands on it.